# Загрузка изображения в зависимости от ширины экрана

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Есть два логотипа: 32px-logotype.png, 16px-logotype.png

Содержимое Header:

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom"

const Header = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className={'header container'}>
            <NavLink to={'/'} className={'logotype'}>
                <img src={require('./32px-logotype.png')} alt={'logotype'}/>
            </NavLink>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

Как мне при разрешение меньше 768px в ширине вывести другую картинку

```
<img src={require('./16px-logotype.png')} alt={'logotype'}/>
```

Грузить сразу две картинки 16 и 32 и потом в css прятать в зависимости от media - так себе вариант, зачем мне грузить картинку на 32 если я сижу с телефона

Comment: можно сделать фоном и медиа-запросами

Comment: нужно именно картинка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нативный метод это использовать `<picture>` https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp

Comment: Просто лучший! Спасибо за помощь!